# Printing pointer-to-uchar values

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printf, clang

When I run the following code on a 64-bit machine (compiler clang)

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

void foo ( byte* a ) {
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
    printf( "%x\n", a );
    std::cout << a << " " << a+1 << std::endl;
}

int main() {

byte a[2];

a[0] = 'A'; a[1] = 'c';
foo( a );

return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
8
ea4c3a9a
Ac c
```

The first line makes sense as this is a 64-bit pointer. However I cannot understand why the second line only has 4 bytes, or the last line, for that matter. Can anyone point out the reason behind the 2nd and 3rd output lines?

**Edit:** Okay, then the question is: how does one correctly create null-terminated byte arrays, and would doing so "correct" the last line?

Comment: FYI, compilers [warn](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZnNDTcGg69bDq6UQ) about the `printf`.

Comment: `a` is not a null-terminated  string,and `%x` is not a valid format for a pointer. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Regarding your last question: 1. provide enough storage - e.g. `byte a[3];` 2. Store a null-terminator after your last contents byte - e.g. `a[0] = 'A'; a[1] = 'c'; a[2] = 0;` (`a[2] = '\0';` would work as well but actually it does the same.) To assign null-terminated strings there is an even simpler way: `byte a[3] = "Ac";`. Thereby, `"Ac"` is compiled as **3** bytes - the null-terminator is added silently. Didn't you read all these things in your C or C++ book? It should be mentioned in either case - probably somewhere in the first 50 pages.

Comment: "However I cannot understand why the second line only has 4 bytes": `"%x"` is a formatter of `unsigned` values. Regardless what you put in the arguments - it will read exactly `sizeof (unsigned)` bytes and print them. Try `sizeof (unsigned)` and you probably will get 4. (Surely not all but a lot of 64 bit C/C++ compilers stick to 32 bit `int`s.) A reference for formatters: [printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, printf_s, fprintf_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Btw. therefore the `printf()` function family is considered as powerful as well as dangerous: If your extra arguments does not match exactly that what's described in the formatter string (with all these `%` sequences) then unexpected things may happen. Therefore, C++ provides a type safe alternative, the `<<` (and `>>`) operators. Btw. did you already decide whether to learn C or C++? (I would concentrate on one of them first. There are certain differences though the latter has been developed out of the former.)

Comment: hey Scheff, thanks for the comments. To get the address in the memory, I tried using `std::cout << std::hex << a` first. This results in `Ac` being output in the 2nd line, not the address of the byte array. That's why I switched to printf. So, with printf, do you know how I can output a hex value of an 8-byte data? Also, your other comments do not seem to explain the 3rd line (using a null-terminated array does not help. A compiler-specific behavior perhaps?).

Comment: As was previously said, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said before, the behavior is undefined. Nevertheless, we can try to understand what happens here.
The 2nd line is a result of the first 4 bytes of a. The printf function expects some unsigned type when %x is in the literal string, and therefore reads the value into an unsigned int or long. 

The 3rd line is just a printing of a char*. Although a is originally a c string, it is passed to the function an unsigned char *. you can perform pointer arithmetics on it. 
 
If a's adress is 0x1000, for example, so: 
`std::cout << a` will print first the chars from 0x1000 until it gets to '\0', and the part `<< a + 1` will print the chars from 0x1001 until it gets to '\0'.

luckily, the 3rd char (that is not *yours*, as a is only 2 chars long) is probably '\0'.

For your question, you can create a null terminating byte array very simple. In initiation you can assign a literal string, like this:

`byte a[3] = "Ac";`
The total size is 3 because you need one byte for '\0'.

Or you can initiate it strcpy, or if reading from file fprintf. It is important to say that the 3rd line is the right output for a null terminating byte* (and it happened "by accident"). If it doesn't seem right to you, you're probably looking for something that should be written differently.

**EDIT:** now that I understand what you wanted to do (i.e. printing the address of a and a + 1), that's how you should do it using std::cout:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a[2];
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(a) << " " << static_cast<void*>(a + 1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x7ffcd22f9700 0x7ffcd22f9701
```

Comment: > `std::cout << a` will print first the chars from 0x1000 until it gets to '\0'

so, this behavior is specific to `cout`, right? Switching to `printf( "%p %p\n", a, a+1 );` did the trick for me.